# Edit Address object in an EditText?

Tags: android, geolocation, street-address

I'm working on an application using Geo Location. I want to let the user change the geo-located address, or enter an address manually in a single EditText. I get the address with : Geocoder.getFromLocation in an Address object. I transform this address to a String to let the user modify it in a Dialog but I don't know how to transform this String back to an address. I was thinking of using some text prediction to let the user chose the address he types but I don't find any informations about that.
Could someone give me a few details ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html).